# Excluding AdMob from Workspace with Multiple Targets with Compilation Conditions

Tags: ios, admob

I've been able to set up a Workspace with several different targets. Only a few of them run ads. Using Google AdMob and I wanted to make sure that the AdMob code was only present in the targets that included advertising.

In Xcode 11, swift 5 - using Cocoapods - I have properly set up the pod file so that the 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' is only included in the correct targets.

My implementation used in Build Settings > Swift Compiler Custom Flag a definition of a flag "-DADS_ON" and then with active compilation conditions (#if ADS_ON) to include the ad serving code. For example:

```
 #if ADS_ON
   @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!
 #else
   @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: UIView!
 #endif
```

and

```
 #if ADS_ON
        bannerView.isHidden = false
        bannerView.adUnitID = AdMobBannerId
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
 #endif
```

By including/excluding certain files from the different targets I've been able to assure that this works correctly for targets with or without the SDK.

I've created a empty GADBannerView

```
@objc(GADBannerView) class GADBannerView : UIView {
// no code here
}
```

so that the targets without ads can also have the same storyboard.

My question: This seems clunky and fragile, are there better methods to exclude the SDK dependent code from the target?

Comment: You can create a 2 file instead of one. first file which is targeted SDK and second file which is targeted to no SDK file. All of them have a same name but different targets.

Comment: Creating two file and including them in different target would work but then has a much larger code management cost - I prefer using #if compilation conditional.